# CEFSHARP Cannot using cef.shutdown in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I run my `cefsharp` application using task scheduler on windows server. I have succeed exit with `Application.exit()`. But the status in task scheduler is still running not stopped.

I think, it was happenned because I didn't use `Cef.shutdown()`. But in this case I am getting error when use this syntax like this :

**`

> Shutdown must be called on the same thread that Initialize was called
>   - typically your UI thread. CefSharp was initialized on ManagedThreadId: 10

`**

Please help to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: what is odd is I get that error when I DON'T call Cef.shutdown

Comment: @GarrGodfrey can you give me the details why that error happened ?

Comment: turned out the Application_Exit event was being posted prematurely.

Comment: idk. CefSharp adds an event handler for Application Exit and detects it wasn't shut down and throws that error. Seems it should happen in your case.

Comment: My guess is you are calling Cef.Initialize from a weird place, not the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue. As the error suggests it does relate to threading, in my example the browser existed on another form which was created on a second thread. A quick solution was to inject the ChromiumBrowser into the constructor of the second form, that way it was disposed correctly from the main thread.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It does **NOT** actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to **comment**.